# CSS collapse/expand div

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<style>
    .faq ul li {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .faq ul li div {
        display: none;
    }

    .faq ul li div:target {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<div class="faq">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#question1">Question 1</a>
            <div id="question1">Answer 1 </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#question2">Question 2</a>
            <div id="question2">Answer 2 </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#question3">Question 3</a>
            <div id="question3">Answer 3 </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#question4">Question 4</a>
            <div id="question4">Answer 4 </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#question5">Question 5</a>
            <div id="question5">Answer 5 </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#question6">Question 6</a>
            <div id="question6">Answer 6 </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I found this great link http://jsfiddle.net/ionko22/4sKD3/ regarding `collapsible` div using CSS. Is there a way to have question 1 always open without clicking on it when you visit the page. And make it collapse when you click on any other questions.
Also is there a way to `close` the div/questions by clicking on itself?
I would be very grateful if you can reply to this.

Comment: You could achieve this with radio buttons to get the first question to display. Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/amwill/4sKD3/824/). Although that method doesn't work for collapsing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/4sKD3/821/

Add this to the CSS to make the first question appear by default:

```
.faq ul li:first-of-type div {
    display: block;
}
```

And add this jQuery for toggling:

```
$(".faq ul li").click(function() {
    if( $( this ).children( "div" ).css( "display" ) == "none" ) {
        $( ".faq ul li div" ).hide();
        $( this ).children( "div" ).show();
    } else {
        $( ".faq ul li div" ).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I think he was impressed by only using CSS and I think he'd like to keep it that way.

Comment: Is it possible with just CSS? You can't check if an element is clicked with CSS, right?

Comment: @chromano there's no way to have it only open (by default) on page load and then close unless you did some unholy selector like :first-of-type:focus and then have the element gain focus. css is about styling at x position, js is meant to help with interactivity, this is clearly an interactivity issue

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing with this for a good two hours now using `first-child`, `.current`, `:not` syntax and a variety of class combinations. I think it's safe to say that displaying the first div to begin with, then having it disappear when another is the `:target` isn't possible with just **pure** CSS and HTML.

I got it to the point where the first question was `display: block;`, and all the others were going on and off when another was active, however the first question was always active throughout.

**So, in answer to your question:**

No, I am 95% sure it is not possible with the markup above, as each div is in its own individual `li`. I was hoping I could prove myself wrong, but I cannot. If someone else can achieve this then they'll certainly be getting an up-vote from me.